# Aside from PHP arrays what is a good structure to handle a collection of PHP objects?

Tags: php, arrays, list, collections

I have a need to manage, handle, and manipulate a [set, collection] of objects.

I am thinking of creating a class that manages set of these objects.

What data structure can I use for this?

Example use:

```
$setManager = new SetManager();
$setManager->getCase($caseNum);
$ave = $setManager->getAverageValueForPropertyXFromAllCases();

$case = new Case();
$setManager->setCase($pos, $case);
```

I can use anything I want inside `SetManager`, I have been using arrays, but my IDE has various issues with using autocomplete on arrays, and I am seeking other structures.

Comment: Why not switch to an IDE that handles arrays well? Seems like an odd statement.

Comment: If your IDE does not handle PHP well change the IDE not PHP

Comment: Sounds like you need a better IDE, not a different data structure.

Comment: I suggest to use an IDE that do not support auto-complete, that way your knowledge of language syntax will become powerful.

Comment: Your IDE is definitely fine, though I wouldn't change arrays nor the IDE. Change PHP for something else. I'd suggest Python or Perl.

Comment: Why use objects?  How about functions with static variables?

Comment: functions with static variables?  How?

Answer (score 1):

- What IDE are you using, it may be a known issue with a resolution?
- What issues with autocomplete are you having?

Most IDE's support annotations or have addons to add support for annotations and autocomplete.

For example

```
/** @var MyObject[]|array $myVar */
$myVar = [];
```

For an actual demonstration of annotation autocomplete on an array of objects.

[image]

You can even specify multiple types of objects that can be in the array and be accepted by a setter method.

Comment: It is the PHPStorm 9.5 IDE with the PHP Annotations plugin